# Derivative of $f(x) = |x|^2 - 2\langle a, x \rangle$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inner-products, maxima-minima

Define the function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = |x|^2 - 2\langle a , x \rangle$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is non-zero. We have:

$$f(x + h) - f(x) = |x+h|^2 - 2\langle a, x + h\rangle - |x|^2 + 2\langle a, x\rangle \\
= |h|^2 - 2\langle x, h\rangle - 2\langle a, h\rangle$$

And thus we have $Df(x)(h) = -2\langle x, h\rangle -2\langle a, h\rangle$. The only critical point is $x = -a$, and given that $D^2f(x)(h, h) = -2|h|^2 < 0$, this critical point is a maxima.

But now let's look at the particular case where $n = 2$ and $a = (1, 0)$. We have $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 2x$. It's derivative is given by:

$$f'(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}2x - 2 & 2y
\end{pmatrix}$$

This has a critical point at $x = 1$ and $y = 0$. Also, we have:

$$f''(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix is positive definite, so the critical point is actually a minima. What is wrong with the general case?

Comment: On the second equality, I used the cosine law:

$$|x + h|^2 = |x|^2 + |h|^2 - 2\langle x, h\rangle$$

Comment: $\langle x+h,x+h \rangle = |x|^2+2\langle x,h \rangle + |h|^2$.

Comment: there is something wrong, the derivative is $$Df(x)h=2\langle x,h\rangle-2\langle a,h\rangle=2\langle x-a,h\rangle$$

Comment: @Siminore I just CAN'T believe I've got THAT wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a sign mistake. Indeed, $x \mapsto |x|^2$ is a quadratic form, hence its derivative is $h \mapsto 2\langle x,h \rangle$.

The second term is linear, and coincides with its derivative. Hence 
$$
Df(x) \colon h \mapsto 2\langle x,h \rangle - 2\langle a,h \rangle.
$$